# How to group opened windows on the taskbar?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, windows, gui, taskbar

Right now on my PI, anytime I open a window it has its own button on the taskbar. If I open 10 more windows, there will be 10 more buttons on the taskbar. I simply want to group them into single button. So, when I click on this button, it will popup list of all the opened windows. Where is the option to have PI do this?

Comment: The default [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Desktop_environments_for_the_X_Window_System) (DE) used on Raspbian is 
[PIXEL](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/), which was recently forked from [LXDE](http://lxde.org/), which has been around for about 10 years; you'll notice they have their own forum and documentation linked there.  I mention this because it may be easier to research that way; PIXEL itself doesn't have much documentation but should be very similar in most respects.  Things like taskbars are part of the DE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, first right click on the taskbar, go to "Taskbar (Window List) Settings", and check off "Combine multiple applications into a single button".